# Sort through linked model with ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to do a sorting of the `Credit` records through the associated models of `CreditPayment`.

**models.py**

```
class Credit(models.Model):
    hot = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class CreditPayment(models.Model):
    credit = models.ForeignKey(Credit)
    period_to = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
```

**views.py**

```
credits = credits.filter(hot=False).distinct().order_by(...)
```

**Example of input data:**

```
Credit #1:
CreditPayment #1:
period_to = 12
rate = 10

CreditPayment #2:      (minimal)
period_to = 10
rate = 8

CreditPayment #3:      
period_to = 9
rate = 10
```

---

```
Credit #2:
CreditPayment #1:        (minimal)
period_to = 6
rate = 20

CreditPayment #2:
period_to = 9
rate = 20
```

---

```
Credit #3:
CreditPayment #1:
period_to = 12
rate = 8

CreditPayment #2:
period_to = 9
rate = 11

CreditPayment #3:       (minimal)
period_to = 9
rate = 8
```

As a result, the sample is reduced to:

```
Credit #1:    
CreditPayment #2:
period_to = 10
rate = 8
```

---

```
Credit #2:
CreditPayment #1:
period_to = 6
rate = 20
```

---

```
Credit #3:
CreditPayment #3:
period_to = 9
rate = 8
```

**Result:**

*Credit #3 -> Credit #1 -> Credit #2*

As you can see, at first the minimum `CreditPayment` was selected for each `Credit` (`credits` at **views.py**). Then, according to these minimum `CreditPayment`, all`Credit` is sorted. If there is a rate for two entries equal, then compare those entries by `period to`. As far as I understand, here you need to somehow apply *aggregation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) & [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

**models.py**

```
class CreditPayment(models.Model):
    credit = models.ForeignKey(Credit, related_name='creditpayments')
    ....
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Max, Min, Prefetch

prefetch = Prefetch('creditpayments', CreditPayment.objects.all())
sorted_credits = Credit.objects.all().prefetch_related(prefetch).annotate(min_rate=Min('creditpayments__rate')).annotate(max_period_to=Max('creditpayments__period_to')).order_by('min_rate', '-max_period_to')
```